# Search combined keywords in a pdf with R

Tags: r, pdf, text, keyword

I have a list of keywords to find text in a group of PDF files, some of the keyword must appear combined to extract the text even if they are not together.

I used the pdfsearch library and it finds text with the separated keywords. I read the documentation but I am not able to find a way to combine the keywords.

My code is as shown below:

```
    library(pdftools)
    library(pdfsearch)
    
    keywords <- c("LOTE","VOLUMEN",
    "LOTE","SOLVENCIA",
    "LOTE","SEGURO",
    "VOLUMEN","TRES ÚLTIMOS",
    "VOLUMEN","3 ÚLTIMOS",
    "VOLUMEN","(3) ÚLTIMOS",
    "NO", "APLICA", "SOLVENCIA")
    
    Results <- keyword_directory(directory,
                                            keyword = keywords,
                                            surround_lines = 1, full_names = TRUE, 
                                            ignore_case = TRUE, remove_hyphen = TRUE)
```

In the keyword assignation, every line is a combination:

```
"LOTE" + "SOLVENCIA",
"LOTE" + "SEGURO",
"VOLUMEN" + "TRES ÚLTIMOS",
"VOLUMEN"+ "3 ÚLTIMOS",
"VOLUMEN" + "(3) ÚLTIMOS",
"NO" + "APLICA" + "SOLVENCIA"
```

For example the combination "NO" + "APLICA" + "SOLVENCIA"

This text should be extracted
"No siempre aplica el uso de solvencia para el proyecto"

This text should no be extracted even if it has the keyword "NO"
"No pueden contar con las listas antes de tiempo"

At the moment I am able just to get the text where the separated keyword appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am assuming you want all keywords in a 'group' of keywords to be present in a single **line**, in order for you to extract that single line. If you want the keywords to be present in a single **file** to extract all text from that file, let me know so I can adjust the answer.*

Indeed `pdfsearch::keyword_search()` searches only individual words. Luckily it does give us a page number and a line number for each result, so we can match those and check if all words from a single group are present in the search results on the same line:

###### Preparation

We start by defining our keywords grouped into vectors, and loading an example file:

```r
library(pdfsearch)
library(dplyr)

# Our list of keywords, grouped in vectors
grouped_keywords <- list(c('saturated','model'),
                 c('vector','specification'),
                 c('framework','inferences'),
                 c('test','that','gives','no','results'),
                 c('population','degree','types'))

# Example file supplied with `pdfsearch`, also available at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.00147.pdf
file <- system.file('pdf', '1610.00147.pdf', package = 'pdfsearch')
```

###### Step 1: search all words individually

To start the search, we perform `keyword_search()` on a flattened version of `grouped_keywords`. This will yield all results we want, but also many results we don't want (lines that only contain one or a few of the keywords in a group).

```r
# Search for individual keywords
individual_results <- keyword_search(file, 
                         keyword = unlist(grouped_keywords), # combine our keyword list into a single 1-dimensional vector
                         path = TRUE)

cat(nrow(individual_results), 'results for individual words\n')
head(individual_results, n=3)
```

Result:

```r
367 results for individual words

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  keyword   page_num line_num line_text token_text
  <chr>        <int>    <int> <list>    <list>    
1 saturated        5      112 <chr [1]> <list [1]>
2 saturated        5      114 <chr [1]> <list [1]>
3 saturated        5      119 <chr [1]> <list [1]>
```

###### Step 2: Merge results for keywords in the same subgroup

For each group of keywords, we look for results that have the same line number and the same page number, ánd that match all keywords in the group:

```r
combined_results <- lapply(grouped_keywords, \(keyword_group) {
  
  individual_results %>%
    filter(keyword %in% keyword_group) %>%
    group_by(page_num, line_num) %>%
    filter(length(unique(keyword)) == length(unique(keyword_group))) %>%
    summarise(keywords = paste(keyword_group, collapse=' + '),
              line_text = line_text[1],
              token_text = token_text[1],
              .groups="keep")
  
})

# Merge list of tibbles to a single tibble
combined_results <- do.call(rbind, combined_results)

# Output result
cat(nrow(combined_results), 'results for combined words\n')
combined_results
```

Result:

```r
8 results for combined words

# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   page_num, line_num [8]
  page_num line_num keywords                    line_text token_text
     <int>    <int> <chr>                       <list>    <list>    
1        5      112 saturated + model           <chr [1]> <list [1]>
2        5      114 saturated + model           <chr [1]> <list [1]>
3        5      119 saturated + model           <chr [1]> <list [1]>
4        7      184 saturated + model           <chr [1]> <list [1]>
5        5      124 vector + specification      <chr [1]> <list [1]>
6        2       32 framework + inferences      <chr [1]> <list [1]>
7        7      168 framework + inferences      <chr [1]> <list [1]>
8        7      187 population + degree + types <chr [1]> <list [1]>
```

---

**Edit 19 July 2022:**

To get only exact matches, it's not enough to add the additional filter constrain which I previously described in the comments; we also need to process that filter rowwise:

```
combined_results <- lapply(grouped_keywords, \(keyword_group) {
  individual_results %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    filter(keyword %in% keyword_group, tolower(keyword) %in% tolower(unlist(token_text))) %>%
    group_by(pdf_name, line_num) %>%
    filter(length(unique(keyword)) == length(unique(keyword_group))) %>%
    summarise(keywords = paste(keyword_group, collapse=' + '),
              line_text = line_text[1],
              token_text = token_text[1],
              .groups="keep")
  
})
```

The complete code, also using `keyword_directory()` instead of `keyword_search()` and matching case-insensitive, becomes:

```
# Preparation -------------------------------------------------------------

library(pdfsearch)
library(dplyr)

# Our list of keywords, grouped in vectors
grouped_keywords <- list(c('individuals','model'),
                         c('information','abundance'),
                         c('individual','ranking'),
                         c('Test','That','Gives','No','Results'),
                         c('population','degree','types'))

grouped_keywords <- lapply(grouped_keywords, tolower)

# Directory containing a few example PDFs:
# https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.00011.pdf
# https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.00039.pdf
# https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.00076.pdf
directory <- "~/Desktop/Rtemp/pdf/"


# Search for individual keywords ------------------------------------------

individual_results <- keyword_directory(directory, 
                                        keyword = unlist(grouped_keywords), # combine our keyword list into a single 1-dimensional vector
                                        split_pdf = TRUE)


cat(nrow(individual_results), 'results for individual words\n')
View(individual_results)


# Merge results for keywords in the same subgroup and file ----------------

combined_results <- lapply(grouped_keywords, \(keyword_group) {
  individual_results %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    filter(keyword %in% keyword_group, tolower(keyword) %in% tolower(unlist(token_text))) %>%
    group_by(pdf_name, line_num) %>%
    filter(length(unique(keyword)) == length(unique(keyword_group))) %>%
    summarise(keywords = paste(keyword_group, collapse=' + '),
              line_text = line_text[1],
              token_text = token_text[1],
              .groups="keep")
  
})

# Merge list of tibbles to a single tibble
combined_results <- do.call(rbind, combined_results)

# Output result
cat(nrow(combined_results), 'results for combined words\n')
combined_results
```

```
> combined_results
# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Groups:   pdf_name, line_num [4]
  pdf_name       line_num keywords                line_text token_text
  <chr>             <int> <chr>                   <list>    <list>    
1 2207.00039.pdf      299 individuals + model     <chr [1]> <list [1]>
2 2207.00076.pdf        4 individuals + model     <chr [1]> <list [1]>
3 2207.00076.pdf       16 individuals + model     <chr [1]> <list [1]>
4 2207.00039.pdf       10 information + abundance <chr [1]> <list [1]>
```

You'll notice I also added `split_pdf = TRUE` to the `keyword_directory()`-call, to improve handling of multi-column PDFs. I have also removed matching on the page number; matching on line number alone is enough.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this is what I was looking for, I wanted to find the words combined in a single line in a set of PDF files so I used keyword_directory instead of keyword_search.

Comment: I have a quick question and was not sure if it need a new all post. I noticed that keyword_search finds text with words like the keywords and not literally the keyword. For example  Keyword "Aplica" finds "aplicante, aplicando, aplicación, aplicar". Is there a way to define that just get exactly the words, i try with ignore_case but changing to TRUE give not results. Once again thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for your help, I  changed the filter but I did not got any result. The code after the change looks like this `combined_results <- lapply(grouped_keywords, \(keyword_group) {
  
  individual_results %>%
    filter(keyword %in% keyword_group, keyword %in% unlist(token_text)) %>%
    group_by(pdf_name, page_num, line_num) %>%
    filter(length(unique(keyword)) == length(unique(keyword_group))) %>%
    summarise(keywords = paste(keyword_group, collapse=' + '),
              line_text = line_text[1],
              token_text = token_text[1],
              .groups="keep")
  
})`

Comment: Hi, since token_text is lower case I made a small change in the code, and I got the same results as the first filter even if the %in% operators does not partial matching but expects complete matching. The the new filter is `filter(keyword %in% keyword_group, tolower(keyword) %in% unlist(token_text))`

Comment: @rcr_aagr: you're correct; it needs to be performed rowwise; I've added an update to the answer (at the end) that properly combines it all.

Comment: Hi @caspar-v Thanks so much for all your help and updates, now the results are with combined keywords and exactly the keywords.